# D+14 days or D-14 days based on value in colum

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to return cars who have a registration date + 14 days and do this every year.

We tried with this:

```
select *
from cars
where date(date_part('year', current_date)||'-'||date_part('month', 
registrationdate)||'-'||date_part('day', registrationdate)) = 
current_date + interval '14 days';
```

But we got problem with year crossing, for example if I have a registration date at 2018-12-20 it won't work.

There is a better solution?

For example, I got this in data :

```
id | registrationdate
1 | 2017-12-20
2 | 2018-01-15
```

and I want to be able with a sql request to return registration date + 14 days, every year.
For our example, it needs to return first row when I launch a request on 2018-01-03, 2019-01-03, 2020-01-03, ... and return second row when I launch request 2018-01-29, 2019-01-29, 2020-01-29, ...

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I am not quiet sure why you are using `current_date`at year part and the registration date at the other parts

Comment: In order to got a reccurent comparison forgeting year, just based on month and day, but problem when a comparison is between two years, 2017-12-20 + 15 days => 2018-01-03 not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you the solution, if it can help someone :

```
select * 
from (
 select *, 
   (extract(year from age(registrationdate)) + 1) * interval '1 year' + interval '14 days' + registrationdate "next_rd_day"
  from cars
) as cars_with_upcoming_registration_date
where
extract(month from age(current_date, next_rd_day))=0 and extract(day from 
age(current_date, next_rd_day))=0
```

It creates a new column with next occurence based on desired interval and in where condition, you just have to test if month and day are same and it's ok.
Too, it's working great with leap year and date near end of the year.